# Define global variable from first line of csv

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, csv, xslt-2.0

I have an xslt file which transforms a csv file into xml.
Here is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="invoice_date" select="tokenize(., ',')[3]"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <transactions>
            <payee_transactions>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\r?\n')">
                    <!-- DETERMINE THE LINE -->
                    <xsl:variable name="line" select="tokenize(., ',')"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$line[1]='$$$'">
                        <xsl:variable name="batch_date" select="$line[3]"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="batch_count" select="$line[4]"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="batch_amount" select="$line[5]"/>
                        <batch_date><xsl:sequence select="normalize-space($batch_date)"/></batch_date>
                        <batch_count><xsl:sequence select="normalize-space($batch_count)"/></batch_count>
                        <batch_amount><xsl:sequence select="normalize-space($batch_amount)"/></batch_amount>
                        <batch_description><xsl:sequence select="normalize-space($batch_reference)"/> - Payees</batch_description>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="$line[1]='PAY'">
                        <payee_transaction>
                            <xsl:variable name="payee_name" select="$line[2]"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="addr1" select="$line[4]"/>
                            <payee_name><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($payee_name)"/></payee_name>
                            <payee_id><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($source_system_id)"/></payee_id>
                            <payee_address_line1><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($addr1)"/></payee_address_line1>
                            <amount><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($amount)"/></amount>
                            <line_memo><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($line_memo)"/></line_memo>
                            <invoice_date><xsl:value-of select="$batch_date"/></invoice_date>
                        </payee_transaction>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>             
            </payee_transactions>
        </transactions>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My main problem is that I get a compiler error when I try to use the `batch_date` variable in the second if statement.

I want each record to have an `invoice_date` which is the same as the `batch_date`.

I looked into global variables, but I come across the same message from people, a global variable can not be re-assigned in a template, a new variable gets created, with that same name.
So, I would like to create a global variable and assign it a value before I hit the template, so I always have it.

I need it to grab the third element from the first line of the csv file.
What I wrote does not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: In your variable what scope do you think is assigned to the period at that point? Have you tried using `/` there instead?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - The error I get is: `Variable batch_date has not been declared`

Comment: @JasonAller - I was thinking the period in the global invoice data variable declaration would reference the input document. Even if it references the entire document, the 3rd element would still be the invoice date.  I am testing with using a slash `/` now.

Comment: @JasonAller - Using the slash worked. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will choose it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the scope for the `invoice_date` variable isn't set because it is outside of any template, which is the fine place for "global" variables.

```
<xsl:variable name="invoice_date" select="tokenize(., ',')[3]"/>
```

Based on that the `.` character doesn't yet have meaning. If it is changed to `/` it should now have scope of the document being processed.

```
<xsl:variable name="invoice_date" select="tokenize(/, ',')[3]"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this sample csv file (**Book1.csv**)

```
<csv>
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
</csv>
```

and this stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:variable name="batch_date">
       <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(document('Book1.csv'), '\r?\n')[2]">
           <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')[3]">
               <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
           </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$batch_date"/>
        </variable>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is

```
<variable>c</variable>
```

see if you can adapt this to your current problem.

Comment: Won't that process `batch_date` from each line rather than from only the first line?